# Interface can see ARP packets but can't see the ICMP echo requests

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ping, ubuntu-14.04

Moring SuperUsers, got my self into a pickle.

I have to servers, `os-net` and `vmhost3`, connected together via a cross-over cable on their respective 10Gbps interfaces. Both servers are running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, the only difference is that `os-net` is virtualized on ESXi. The VM has it's own VMKernel port attaching it to the 10Gbps interface on the ESXi server.

The problem I am having is trying to get the two servers to communicate to each other, if I ping `os-net` via `vmhost3` (`ping -c 4 10.0.0.2`) it sends the ARP request and gets a response but when it sends the ICMP echo request it gets no reply.

Here is a capture from wire shark on `os-net` (tshark -i eth0)

```
Capturing on 'eth0'
  1   0.000000     10.0.0.3 -> 10.0.0.2     ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x6587, seq=1/256, ttl=64
  2   0.000566 Vmware_f8:61:3c -> Broadcast    ARP 42 Who has 10.0.0.3?  Tell 10.0.0.2
  3   0.000959 Dell_f1:f5:ba -> Vmware_f8:61:3c ARP 60 10.0.0.3 is at bc:30:5b:f1:f5:ba
  4   0.997477 Vmware_f8:61:3c -> Broadcast    ARP 42 Who has 10.0.0.3?  Tell 10.0.0.2
  5   0.998023 Dell_f1:f5:ba -> Vmware_f8:61:3c ARP 60 10.0.0.3 is at bc:30:5b:f1:f5:ba
  6   1.006226     10.0.0.3 -> 10.0.0.2     ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x6587, seq=2/512, ttl=64
  7   1.997455 Vmware_f8:61:3c -> Broadcast    ARP 42 Who has 10.0.0.3?  Tell 10.0.0.2
  8   1.997830 Dell_f1:f5:ba -> Vmware_f8:61:3c ARP 60 10.0.0.3 is at bc:30:5b:f1:f5:ba
  9   2.014184     10.0.0.3 -> 10.0.0.2     ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x6587, seq=3/768, ttl=64
  10   3.022275     10.0.0.3 -> 10.0.0.2     ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x6587, seq=4/1024, ttl=64
  11   3.022353 Vmware_f8:61:3c -> Broadcast    ARP 42 Who has 10.0.0.3?  Tell 10.0.0.2
  12   3.022810 Dell_f1:f5:ba -> Vmware_f8:61:3c ARP 60 10.0.0.3 is at bc:30:5b:f1:f5:ba
  13   4.021434 Vmware_f8:61:3c -> Broadcast    ARP 42 Who has 10.0.0.3?  Tell 10.0.0.2
  14   4.021797 Dell_f1:f5:ba -> Vmware_f8:61:3c ARP 60 10.0.0.3 is at bc:30:5b:f1:f5:ba
  15   5.021464 Vmware_f8:61:3c -> Broadcast    ARP 42 Who has 10.0.0.3?  Tell 10.0.0.2
  16   5.021960 Dell_f1:f5:ba -> Vmware_f8:61:3c ARP 60 10.0.0.3 is at bc:30:5b:f1:f5:ba
```

If I try the reverse and try and ping `vmhost3` from `os-net` I get this capture (tshark -i em2)

```
Capturing on 'em2'
  1   0.000000 Vmware_f8:61:3c -> Broadcast    ARP 60 Who has 10.0.0.3?  Tell 10.0.0.2
  2   0.000038 Dell_f1:f5:ba -> Vmware_f8:61:3c ARP 42 10.0.0.3 is at bc:30:5b:f1:f5:ba
  3   0.999355 Vmware_f8:61:3c -> Broadcast    ARP 60 Who has 10.0.0.3?  Tell 10.0.0.2
  4   0.999376 Dell_f1:f5:ba -> Vmware_f8:61:3c ARP 42 10.0.0.3 is at bc:30:5b:f1:f5:ba
  5   1.999370 Vmware_f8:61:3c -> Broadcast    ARP 60 Who has 10.0.0.3?  Tell 10.0.0.2
  6   1.999391 Dell_f1:f5:ba -> Vmware_f8:61:3c ARP 42 10.0.0.3 is at bc:30:5b:f1:f5:ba
  7   2.999564 Vmware_f8:61:3c -> Broadcast    ARP 60 Who has 10.0.0.3?  Tell 10.0.0.2
  8   2.999586 Dell_f1:f5:ba -> Vmware_f8:61:3c ARP 42 10.0.0.3 is at bc:30:5b:f1:f5:ba
  9   3.999327 Vmware_f8:61:3c -> Broadcast    ARP 60 Who has 10.0.0.3?  Tell 10.0.0.2
  10   3.999347 Dell_f1:f5:ba -> Vmware_f8:61:3c ARP 42 10.0.0.3 is at bc:30:5b:f1:f5:ba
  11   4.999358 Vmware_f8:61:3c -> Broadcast    ARP 60 Who has 10.0.0.3?  Tell 10.0.0.2
  12   4.999385 Dell_f1:f5:ba -> Vmware_f8:61:3c ARP 42 10.0.0.3 is at bc:30:5b:f1:f5:ba
```

Any help is welcome and thanked!